# RemoteViews and addView (horizontal) : only the first item (view) is showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-widget, remoteview

I working on a widget and I have a trouble with adding view into my `RemoteView`.

Only the first item (view) added is showing.

PS : I need to add views horizontally.

This is my loop for adding views into my `RemoteViews` :

```
RemoteViews mainView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
mainView.removeAllViews(R.id.view_container);
for (int i = 0; i < Constant.max; i++) {
   RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.item);
   newView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.logo, Constant.data[i].getLogo());
   mainView.addView(R.id.view_container, newView);
   Log.e("Item added : ", Constant.data[i].getName());
}
```

**widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center">

   <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:id="@+id/view_container"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_between"
       android:background="#F0F0F0"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="2dp">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/logo"
           android:layout_width="48dp"
           android:layout_height="48dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you have any idea to solve this problem.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the width of your parent layout in **item.xml** to `wrap_content`.

Because with `fill_parent` it will cover the whole width of your container (`view_container`) and there wont be an available space for the other items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_between"
       android:background="#F0F0F0"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="2dp">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/logo"
           android:layout_width="48dp"
           android:layout_height="48dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**PS:** Maybe it's better to use a `HorizontalScrollView` if you have many images